# How to avoid overriding in InnoSetup silent mode?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to use the silent mode of InnoSetup. I have to update the "License" key value if specified in silent mode installation.
This is how I configured the Inno file:

```
[INI]
Filename: define.ini; Section: "General"; Key: "License"; String: "{param:LICENSE}"; Check: WizardSilent;
```

It works good when the user installs the application this way:

> setup.exe /SILENT /LICENSE=licensekey

The problem occurs when I want to skip the /LICENSE parameter (since it's already configured and I don't want to change this. For instance: when installing a patch kit).
Using the following way overrides "License" key on INI file and just leave it empty:

> setup.exe /SILENT

How to avoid this? I just want NOT to change the "License" value in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two options since you are using a custom parameter. Either you can define a default value for the [`{param}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=param) constant to be the existing value read from the same INI file:

```
[INI]
...; String: "{param:LICENSE|{ini:define.ini,General,License|}}"
```

The above statement writes to the given INI file value passed by the `LICENSE` command line parameter, or if it's not specified reads the same value from the same file. So it actually overwrites the value with the same value if the parameter is not specified, which is not much clean in my view.

Or, you may extend your existing [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck&anchor=Check) parameter by the helper function like follows. This is the way I would prefer, since you just skip processing of the entry instead of overwriting the same value when the parameter is not specified:

```
[INI]
...; Check: WizardSilent and CmdLineParamExists('/LICENSE')

[Code]
function CmdLineParamExists(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;  
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
    if CompareText(ParamStr(I), Value) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @TLama. I finally used the first option and it works for me. I firstly tried the second option but it did not work when I omitted the parameter.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, I've tested both and both worked for me. It reads as *process the entry when setup runs silent and /LICENSE parameter is found*.